# Why is there no Like button on a Facebook page of a charity organization?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

Take [this one](https://www.facebook.com/hurkit.bf/) for example. The category is Charity Organization.

I tried to create a page myself, and it seems to have the Like button. Although it's hidden in the kebab menu:

[image]

And well, I'm not sure if it's available for other users.

To make it clear, the question is not about creating a page. It's about the fact that I can't like a page of a charity organization.